# PostgreSQL installation hangs after password prompt

Tags: postgresql, apt, dpkg

I am trying to install PostgreSQL on an AWS cloud CPU instance (instance type: [c5.24xlarge](https://aws.amazon.com/ec2/instance-types/c5/), Ubuntu 20.04 LTS).

I have tried both `sudo apt install postgresql postgresql-contrib`, as well as installing from the apt repository mentioned in the [official documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/download/linux/ubuntu/).

However, in both cases the installation keeps freezing at this point:

```
Setting up postgresql-common (247.pgdg20.04+1) ...
Password:
```

Here after I enter a password and press enter, nothing happens and the installation seems to be stuck.

Then if I cancel via Ctrl+C or Ctrl+D, it blocks any further installations and I need to kill all apt and dpkg processes, delete the dpkg lock files, and purge postgresql from my system before trying again.

I have been stuck on this for a while...is there any way to fix this issue and install postgresql? Thanks

Comment: I certainly can't reproduce that.  Are you using the official ubuntu 20.04 machine image?

Comment: Other then the `sudo` password I have never been asked for a password in the subsequent install. 1) Are you sure you are pointed at correct repo? 2) Did you do all the steps in the section  *To use the apt repository, follow these steps:*. In particular `wget --quiet -O - https://www.postgresql.org/media/keys/ACCC4CF8.asc | sudo apt-key add -` and if so did it succeed?

Comment: The image is official, yes. The apt repository key was added successfully.

Comment: I'm currently having the same issue. Any luck fixing it?